# Huge Fraction that doesn't fit in page

Tags: equations

I have a huge fraction that doesn't fit the page. I searched this forum and found only `\begin{split}`, or `align*`, etc but I don't think these are what I want. They split equations at signs, but in  my case, both the numerator and denominator of the fraction have enough elements as to not fit in the page. (I cannot simplify it anymore)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}    

    $ \Leftrightarrow \theta_{0|t+1}\approx \frac{\displaystyle(\beta+1)\frac{P(y|\Theta_{t+1})}{P(y|\Theta_{t})}\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T(y_k- \phi_{1|t+1}(s_k))y_{k-1}+(1-\beta)\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T(y_k- \phi_{1|t+1}(s_k))y_{k-1}}{\displaystyle(\beta+1)\frac{P(y|\Theta_{t+1})}{P(y|\Theta_{t})}\sum_{s \in S} P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T ( \phi_{0|t+1}(s_k)+y_{k-1})y_{k-1}+(1-\beta)\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T ( \phi_{0|t+1}(s_k)+y_{k-1})y_{k-1}} $
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  A useful solution is going to depend on the actual use case -- otherwise you could resize the fraction, or break the fraction into components.

Comment: The reader probably doesn't want to see a fraction that big anyway: you can always split it up: `\[\frac{a}{b}\] where \[a=...\] and \[b=...\]`

Comment: Proably you'll need to find another way to express that large fraction using algebra. But without a MWE is hard to say.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for your interest. I've just added some code.

Comment: @Aradnix Thanks for your interest. I've just added some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to inflict such a monster formula to your readers, I see nothing else than splitting numerator and denominator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\theta_{0|t+1}\approx
  \frac{
    \begin{multlined}
    (\beta+1)\frac{P(y|\Theta_{t+1})}{P(y|\Theta_{t})}
      \sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T(y_k- \phi_{1|t+1}(s_k))y_{k-1}+{} \\
    (1-\beta)\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})
      \sum_{k=1}^T(y_k- \phi_{1|t+1}(s_k))y_{k-1}
    \end{multlined}
  }{
    \begin{multlined}
    (\beta+1)\frac{P(y|\Theta_{t+1})}{P(y|\Theta_{t})}
      \sum_{s \in S} P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T ( \phi_{0|t+1}(s_k)+y_{k-1})y_{k-1}+{}\\
    (1-\beta)\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T
      ( \phi_{0|t+1}(s_k)+y_{k-1})y_{k-1}
    \end{multlined}
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But defining abbreviations for the four parts would be surely much better; something like

```
\[
\theta_{0|t+1}\approx\frac{A(t)+B(t)}{C(t)+D(t)}
\]
where
\begin{align*}
A(t) &= (\beta+1)\frac{P(y|\Theta_{t+1})}{P(y|\Theta_{t})}
        \sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T(y_k- \phi_{1|t+1}(s_k))y_{k-1} \\
B(t) &= (1-\beta)\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})
        \sum_{k=1}^T(y_k- \phi_{1|t+1}(s_k))y_{k-1} \\
C(t) &= (\beta+1)\frac{P(y|\Theta_{t+1})}{P(y|\Theta_{t})}
        \sum_{s \in S} P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T ( \phi_{0|t+1}(s_k)+y_{k-1})y_{k-1} \\
D(t) &= (1-\beta)\sum_{s \in S}P(s|y;\Theta_{t+1})\sum_{k=1}^T
        ( \phi_{0|t+1}(s_k)+y_{k-1})y_{k-1}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: In the first suggestion, should the `+` not be on the next line in both the numerator and denominator?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I prefer leaving them in the line above, in order to make clear the formula is still incomplete; it's a matter of opinion and both ways are “right”.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Let
\begin{align*}
  A &= \frac{P(y \mid \Theta_{t + 1})}{P(y \mid \Theta_{t})},\\
  B &= \sum_{s \in S} P(s \mid y; \Theta_{t + 1}),\\
  C &= \sum_{k = 1}^{T} (y_{k} - \phi_{1 \mid t + 1}(s_{k}))y_{k - 1},\\
  D &= \sum_{k = 1}^{T} (\phi_{0 \mid t + 1}(s_{k}) + y_{k - 1})y_{k - 1}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
  \theta_{0 \mid t + 1}
  \approx \frac{(1 + \beta)ABC + (1 - \beta)BC}{(1 + \beta)ABD + (1 - \beta)BD}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, its not AB like but more like $\sum_i A_i \sum_j B_ij$

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I don't understand what you mean. Can't you just rename it accordingly or am I missing something?

Comment: Its not a multiplication of summations, but summations inside summations, and the interior summations are dependent on the index of the outside summation.

Comment: And does that effect what I wrote in my first comment? Why can't you just change the notation accoding to your needs?

Comment: Your simplification at the last equality is not true. But the rest can be used. ;)

Comment: Okay. Answer edited.